# Flutter - Row Multiline with Containers

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, row, overflow

I have a Row with some Containers in it, this causes an overflowed on the right.
How can I make that once a container has overflowed, the next ones go in a new line

I hope I was clear and that someone can answer me.
Thank you :)

Comment: use Wrap() instead  of Row()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a Row() widget you need to use a Wrap() widget and make sure to have your Container()'s width not overflowed.
Wrap() widget just do according to what you need right now, it arranges its children in horizontal direction(by default - you can change it though) and if any child overflowed then move that child in new line.

Comment: How to know/detect overflowed child?